# Fetch Skype history

Tags: sqlite, message, archive, restore, skype

Is there any way to restore last Skype messages from your contacts if you have fresh installed Skype instance?

Is there any SQL-hook for main.db with timestamp updates, so Skype will try to fetch 'unreceived' messages again from my contacts?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Do you have the `main.db` file with the messages you're after, or are you trying to get Skype to create a new `main.db` file and populate it with data pulled from the central Skype servers?

Comment: Yes, I'd like Skype to create a new database file (main.db) and fill it with data from servers, if it is possible.

Comment: The Skype service is not documented and third-party clients are not supported. AFAIK all you can do is fire-up a new instance of the client and hope it downloads the history eventually, but I don't know how to trigger it - nor for how long the official servers store conversation history for.